# Anyone know a good PHP contacts application?

Tags: php, database, contacts

I'm looking for an open-source contact database application, preferably written in PHP5. Anyone know of a good one? I'm not looking for a full-blown CRM system, just something with a contact entry form, a backend for adding/removing contacts and maybe even a search system.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try these ..

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-addressbook/

http://www.simplecustomer.com/

http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/10/22/php-mysql-and-contact-management-contacts-01/

Comment: thanks! Had not seen php-addressbook. Looks a bit more feature-complete than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress to the rescue: http://wpcandy.com/articles/tutorials/freelancing-with-wordpress-contact-management.html